# Virtual Product not showing COD option in my website

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery, virtual-products

I have added a virtual product on my magento website. I wanted to disable the cod option for this product. I made some changes and then that particular product didn't showed COD option as a payment method. But later on I discovered that the product showed error while placing the order and didn't get redirected to the payement gateway page. It is showing these set of errors while placing order.

[image: The first error while placing order]

[image: The second error if I refresh the above page]

I don't remember the earlier changes I made. Need help

```
<?php

class Payu_PayuCheckout_Model_Shared extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {

    protected $_code = 'payucheckout_shared';
    protected $_isGateway = false;
    protected $_canAuthorize = false;
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
    protected $_canRefund = false;
    protected $_canVoid = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal = false;
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
    protected $_formBlockType = 'payucheckout/shared_form';
    protected $_paymentMethod = 'shared';
    protected $_order;

    public function cleanString($string) {

        $string_step1 = strip_tags($string);
        $string_step2 = nl2br($string_step1);
        $string_step3 = str_replace("<br />", "<br>", $string_step2);
        $cleaned_string = str_replace("\"", " inch", $string_step3);
        return $cleaned_string;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkout session namespace
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Session
     */
    public function getCheckout() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

    /**
     * Get current quote
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    public function getQuote() {
        return $this->getCheckout()->getQuote();
    }

    /**
     * Get order model
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getOrder() {
        if (!$this->_order) {
            $paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
            $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->loadByIncrementId($paymentInfo->getOrder()->getRealOrderId());
        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    public function getCustomerId() {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/customer_id');
    }

    public function getAccepteCurrency() {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/currency');
    }

    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
        return Mage::getUrl('payucheckout/shared/redirect');
    }

    /**
     * prepare params array to send it to gateway page via POST
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFormFields() {

        $billing = $this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress();
        $shipping = $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
        $addr_entity_id = $shipping->getCustomerAddressId();
        $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
        $shippingaddress->load($addr_entity_id);
        $shipaddgetdat = $shippingaddress->getData();



        $biladdr_entity_id = $billing->getCustomerAddressId();
        ;
        $billingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
        $billingaddress->load($biladdr_entity_id);
        $billaddgetdat = $billingaddress->getData();

        $coFields = array();
        $items = $this->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        if ($items) {
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $coFields['c_prod_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getSku());
                $coFields['c_name_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getName());
                $coFields['c_description_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getDescription());
                $coFields['c_price_' . $i] = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');
                $i++;
            }
        }

        $request = '';
        foreach ($coFields as $k => $v) {
            $request .= '<' . $k . '>' . $v . '</' . $k . '>';
        }


        $key = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/key');
        $salt = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/salt');
        $debug_mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/debug_mode');

        $orderid = $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
        $orderInfo = $this->getOrder();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
// get order total value
        $orderValue = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', $thousands_sep = '');
// get order item collection
        $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
        $productInfo = array();
        $productInfo2 = array();


        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

            $item->getName();
            $product_id = $item->product_id;
            $product_sku = $item->sku;
            $product_name = $item->getName();
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
            $category_id = $cats[0]; // just grab the first id
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
            $category_name = $category->getName();

           // $productInfo['name'] = $this->cleanString($item->getName());
            //$productInfo['description'] = $this->cleanString(substr($_product->getDescription(),0,50));
            //$productInfo['value'] = $orderValue;
            //$productInfo['isRequired'] = true;
            //$productInfo['settlementEvent'] = "EmailConfirmation";
            //$productInfo2[] = $productInfo;
        }
       // $productIndoFilterData['paymentParts'] = $productInfo2;
        //$jsonProductInfo = json_encode($productIndoFilterData);

        $txnid = $orderid;
        $productinfo = 'Product Information';
        $coFields['key'] = $key;
        $coFields['txnid'] = $txnid;
        $coFields['udf2'] = $txnid;
        $coFields['amount'] = number_format($this->getOrder()->getBaseGrandTotal(), 0, '', '');
        $coFields['productinfo'] = $productinfo;
        $coFields['address'] = $billaddgetdat['street'];
        $coFields['firstname'] = $billing->getFirstname();
        $coFields['Lastname'] = $billing->getLastname();
        $coFields['City'] = $billing->getCity();
        $coFields['State'] = $billing->getRegion();
        $coFields['Country'] = $billing->getCountry();
        $coFields['Zipcode'] = $billing->getPostcode();
        $coFields['email'] = $this->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
        $coFields['phone'] = $billing->getTelephone();

        $coFields['ship_name'] = $shipping->getFirstname() . " " . $shipping->getLastname();
        $coFields['ship_address'] = $shipaddgetdat['street'];
        $coFields['ship_zipcode'] = $shipping->getPostcode();
        $coFields['ship_city'] = $shipping->getCity();
        $coFields['ship_state'] = $shipping->getRegion();
        $coFields['ship_country'] = $shipping->getCountry();
        $coFields['ship_phone'] = $shipping->getTelephone();
        $coFields['website'] = Mage::getBaseUrl();
        $coFields['surl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/success/';
        $coFields['furl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/failure/';
        $coFields['curl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/canceled/id/' . $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
        $coFields['Pg'] = $billing->getpg();
        $coFields['bankcode'] = $billing->getbankcode();
        $coFields['ccnum'] = $billing->getccnum();
        $coFields['ccvv'] = $billing->getccvv();
        $coFields['ccexpmon'] = $billing->getccexpmon();
        $coFields['ccexpyr'] = $billing->getccexpyr();
        $coFields['ccname'] = $billing->getccname();
        $coFields['service_provider'] = 'payu_paisa';

        $debugId = '';


        if ($debug_mode == 1) {

            $requestInfo = $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                    $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '|' . $debugId . '||||||||||' . $salt;
            $debug = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')
                    ->setRequestBody($requestInfo)
                    ->save();

            $debugId = $debug->getId();

            $coFields['udf1'] = $debugId;
            $coFields['Hash'] = hash('sha512', $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                    $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '|' . $debugId . '|' . $coFields['udf2'] . '|||||||||' . $salt);
        } else {
            $coFields['Hash'] = strtolower(hash('sha512', $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                            $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '||' . $coFields['udf2'] . '|||||||||' . $salt));
        }
        return $coFields;
    }

    /**
     * Get url of Payu payment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPayuCheckoutSharedUrl() {
        $mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/demo_mode');

        $url = 'https://test.payu.in/_payment.php';

        if ($mode == '') {
            $url = 'https://secure.payu.in/_payment.php';
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Get debug flag
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDebug() {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/debug_flag');
    }

    public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
        $payment->setStatus(self::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setLastTransId($this->getTransactionId());

        return $this;
    }

    public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment) {
        $payment->setStatus(self::STATUS_DECLINED)
                ->setLastTransId($this->getTransactionId());

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * parse response POST array from gateway page and return payment status
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function parseResponse() {

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Return redirect block type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRedirectBlockType() {
        return $this->_redirectBlockType;
    }

    /**
     * Return payment method type string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaymentMethodType() {
        return $this->_paymentMethod;
    }

    public function getResponseOperation($response) {

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $debug_mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/debug_mode');
        $key = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/key');
        $salt = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/salt');

        if (isset($response['status'])) {
            $txnid = $response['txnid'];
            $orderid = $response['udf2'];
            if ($response['status'] == 'success') {

                $status = $response['status'];
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
                $amount = $response['amount'];
                $productinfo = $response['productinfo'];
                $firstname = $response['firstname'];
                $email = $response['email'];
                $keyString = '';
                $Udf1 = $response['udf1'];
                $Udf2 = $response['udf2'];
                $Udf3 = $response['udf3'];
                $Udf4 = $response['udf4'];
                $Udf5 = $response['udf5'];
                $Udf6 = $response['udf6'];
                $Udf7 = $response['udf7'];
                $Udf8 = $response['udf8'];
                $Udf9 = $response['udf9'];
                $Udf10 = $response['udf10'];
                if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                    $keyString = $key . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $email . '|' . $Udf1 . '|' . $Udf2 . '|' . $Udf3 . '|' . $Udf4 . '|' . $Udf5 . '|' . $Udf6 . '|' . $Udf7 . '|' . $Udf8 . '|' . $Udf9 . '|' . $Udf10;
                } else {
                    $keyString = $key . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $email . '|' . $Udf1 . '|' . $Udf2 . '|' . $Udf3 . '|' . $Udf4 . '|' . $Udf5 . '|' . $Udf6 . '|' . $Udf7 . '|' . $Udf8 . '|' . $Udf9 . '|' . $Udf10;
                }

                $keyArray = explode("|", $keyString);
                $reverseKeyArray = array_reverse($keyArray);
                $reverseKeyString = implode("|", $reverseKeyArray);
                $saltString = $salt . '|' . $status . '|' . $reverseKeyString;
                $sentHashString = strtolower(hash('sha512', $saltString));
                $responseHashString = $_REQUEST['hash'];
                if ($sentHashString == $responseHashString) {
                    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
                    $order->save();
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                } else {

                    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
                    $order->cancel()->save();
                }

                if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                    $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                    $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                    $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                    $model->setId($id)->save();
                }
            }

            if ($response['status'] == 'failure') {
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
                // Inventory updated 
                $this->updateInventory($orderid);

                $order->cancel()->save();

                if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                    $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                    $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                    $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                    $model->setId($id)->save();
                }
            } else if ($response['status'] == 'pending') {
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
                // Inventory updated  
                $this->updateInventory($orderid);
                $order->cancel()->save();

                if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                    $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                    $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                    $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                    $model->setId($id)->save();
                }
            }
        } else {

            $order->loadByIncrementId($response['id']);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
            // Inventory updated 
            $order_id = $response['id'];
            $this->updateInventory($order_id);

            $order->cancel()->save();
        }
    }

    public function updateInventory($order_id) {

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $itemId => $item) {
            $ordered_quantity = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
            $sku = $item->getSku();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->getQty();

            $updated_inventory = $qtyStock + $ordered_quantity;

            $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
            $stockData->setData('qty', $updated_inventory);
            $stockData->save();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, show the code of the corresponding file: `app/code/community/Payu/PayuCheckout/Model/Shared.php`

Comment: added the code for the shared.php page, Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with validation in this method:

```
public function getFormFields() {

    $billing = $this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress();
    $shipping = $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
    $addr_entity_id = $shipping->getCustomerAddressId();
    $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
    $shippingaddress->load($addr_entity_id);
    $shipaddgetdat = $shippingaddress->getData();
```

As you are using the virtual product, your order has no shipping address. Before use of a shipping address, try to check whether the order is virtual (if this is so - use the billing address instead of shipping):

```
public function getFormFields() {

    $billing = $this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress();
    if ($this->getOrder()->getIsVirtual()) {
        $shipping = $billing;
    } else {
        $shipping = $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
    }
    $addr_entity_id = $shipping->getCustomerAddressId();
    $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
    $shippingaddress->load($addr_entity_id);
    $shipaddgetdat = $shippingaddress->getData();
```

This is a "hot fix". You should not use the shipping address in a case when the order is virtual. Your code needs fuller refactoring.

Comment: Its working great, thankyou for the help. Also, how to refactor the code, since I am afraid of messing around with code.

Comment: @MohammadAnasSiddiquei You need to divide your big method into small parts (methods) and at the beginning you should validate the shipping address availability (whether the order is virtual). It is necessary to work with the abstract address, but not the specific address type. If my answer was helpful for you, plaese, accept it as solution.

Comment: Yes, your solution is working fine now. Thankyou!!